How do I set the value of a cell to be the same as the cell above when inserting a row via VBA
I am new to VBA and so far able to rejig existing code but not very good at writing it.
I am trying to insert a new row based on the value of column B. I would like column A and B to have the same values as the row above.
This is the code I have so far:
Sub insertrow()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 1000
        j = InStr(1, Cells(i, 2), "Mon", vbTextCompare)
        If j = 1 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = (i - 1)
            Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = (i - 1)
            Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = "ERP"
            i = i + 2
        Else
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

At the moment (i - 1) is giving the row number -1 which is not quite what I want.

Table as it starts

Table as I want it to appear after Macro
Sorry if this is really basic!

Could you share some relevant sample data using this Table to Markdown Generator so we have something to work with. Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question).

What is the formula in the B column? If there is no formula, are there only 3 characters in each row or is it a the same date to the right formatted as ddd?

Insert Matching Rows

Sub InsertMondayRows()

    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, specify it by name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Calculate the last row in the 'Day' column.
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Turn off screen updating to increase efficiency.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare additional variables
    Dim cell As Range, Row As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the table from the bottom to the top.
    For Row = LastRow To FIRST_ROW Step -1
        ' Reference the cell in the current row of the 'Day' column.
        Set cell = ws.Cells(Row, "B")
        ' Check if it's a match. Use 'CStr' to prevent a type mismatch error
        ' when the cell contains an error.
        If StrComp(CStr(cell.Value), "Mon", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' equal
        'If InStr(1, CStr(cell.Value), "Mon", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then ' begins w
            ' Reference the current entire row (range).
            With cell.EntireRow
                ' Insert a new row below the current row copying its formatting.
                .Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, _
                    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                ' Copy the values from columns 'A' and 'B' from the current row
                ' to the same columns of the inserted row.
                .Offset(1).Columns("A").Value = .Columns("A").Value
                .Offset(1).Columns("B").Value = .Columns("B").Value
                ' Write to column 'C' of the inserted row.
                .Offset(1).Columns("C").Value = "ERP"
            End With
        'Else ' no match; do nothing
        End If
    Next Row

    ' Turn on screen updating here to be able to see
    ' the result (inserted rows) behind the message box.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Monday rows inserted.", vbInformation

End Sub


If insert or delete rows in a table it is recommended to do it from bottom to up.
Modifying the cycle counter can be done, but very much not recommended.
Considered these this is the modified code which inserts the row after Mon or Thu
Sub insdup()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet  'select the sheet where data are
For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If Left(ws.Cells(i, 2), 3) = "Mon" Or Left(ws.Cells(i, 2), 3) = "Thu" Then
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2)
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = "ERP"
  End If
Next i
End Sub


To compare texts case independent apply UCase(text1) = Ucase(text2).
